# Let $H ≤ F_A$ be finitely generated and $g \in F_A$. Show that it is decidable if $xgx^{-1} \in H$ for some $x \in F_A$

Tags: group-theory, automata, free-groups

By the generalized word theorem, we know that if we have $H ≤ F_A$ finitely generated and $g \in F_A$, then $g \in H$ iff $\overline{g}$ is accepted in $S_H$ (Stalling's Automata of H).

Then, $xgx^{-1} \in H$ is simply saying that $\overline{x g x^{-1}}= \overline{x} \overline{g} \overline{x^{-1}}$ is accepted by $S_H$.

I'm not sure where to go from this ...

If $\overline{x g x^{-1}}$ is accepted by $S_H$, then $S_H$, must have a tail $\overline{x}$. If doesn't we can already say that $xgx^{-1} \not\in H$. If has a tail, then if we remove the tail, we get an automata that must accept $\overline{g}$.

Is that it?

$F_A$ is the free group with base $A$.

$\overline{x}$ is the reduced form of $x$.

Comment: If $H$ is finitely generated by $a_1, \dots ,a_n$, don’t we have $$S_H = S_{\{a_1, \dots ,a_n\}}$$

Comment: Plus if you could give some details about the notations and objects you are using it would be nice, I’m not sure about the nature of each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can replace $g$ by a conjugate, we can assume that $g$ is cyclically reduced, and that the reduced word for $xgx^{-1}$ is $wg'w^{-1}$ for some word $w$, where $g'$ is a cyclic conjugate of $g$.

If there is a repeated state when reading $w$ through the Stallings automaton of $H$, then we have $w=w_1w_2w_3$ where the states after reading $w_1$ and $w_1w_2$ are the same.

So $Hw_1 = Hw_1w_2$, and then $wg'w^{-1} \in H$ if and only if $w_1w_3g'(w_3w_1)^{-1} \in H$.

So we can assume that the length of $w$ is at most the number of states of the Stallings automaton for $H$, which reduces the problem to a finite number of tests of elements for membership of $H$.